# Не срабатывающий ajax

Tags: php, html, css, jquery, ajax

Есть сайт

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css">-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commons.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="subcategory.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="template.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.bundle.css" media="all"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components.bundle.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerIndex.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexIndex.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles__ltr.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic" media="all">

  <!-- <script>
 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    let sidemenu = document.querySelector('#sidemenu');
    sidemenu.addEventListener("mouseover", checkitem);
    sidemenu.addEventListener("mouseleave", checkitem);
 
    function checkitem(event) {
        if (event.target && event.target.closest(".fa")) sidemenu.classList.add("active");
        if (event.type === "mouseleave") sidemenu.classList.remove("active");
    }
});
</script> -->

</head>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="testsite.js"> -->

<body class="bodyclass">
  <header id="pageHeader">
  </header>
  <div class="contentpart">
    <div class="leftmenu">
      <nav class="menu">
        <ul id="sidemenu" class="level1">
          <li>
            <div class="leftside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="centerplace">
              <a href="" class="nestedblock">Техника для кухни</a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="level2">
              <li class="submenu">
                <ul>
                  <li class="submenu__title">
                    <a href="#">Крупная бытовая техника</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <ul>
                  <li class="submenu__title">
                    <a href="#">New title</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Холодильники</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные камеры</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Морозильные лари</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="submenu__item">
                    <a href="#">Плиты газовые </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="leftside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="centerplace">
              <a href="" class="nestedblock">Бытовая техника для дома</a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="leftside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="centerplace">
              <a href="" class="nestedblock">Ноутбуки и компьютеры</a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="leftside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="centerplace">
              <a href="" class="nestedblock">Комплектующие</a>
            </div>
            <div class="rightside">
              <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
            </div>
          </li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>

    <div class="centerarea">
    </div>

    <div class="rightmenu">
    </div>
  </div>


  <footer id="pageFooter">
    <div class="b-footer__container">
      <div class="b-footer-menu">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="0">
              <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/about-us">
              Интернет-магазин
            </a>
              <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="0" style="display: none;">
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/about-us" class="b-footer-menu__link">О нас</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/delivery" class="b-footer-menu__link">Доставка</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/pay" class="b-footer-menu__link">Оплата</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/kredit" class="b-footer-menu__link">Покупка в кредит</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/e-catalog" class="b-footer-menu__link">Электронный каталог</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/special-offers" class="b-footer-menu__link">Акции</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/news" class="b-footer-menu__link">Новости</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/reviews" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обзоры</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/personal" class="b-footer-menu__link">Условия продажи<br> и политика обработки<br> персональных данных</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/card2card" class="b-footer-menu__link">Денежные переводы<br> с карты на карту</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/creditpayment" class="b-footer-menu__link">Оплата кредита онлайн</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/services/moneytransfer" class="b-footer-menu__link">Денежные переводы онлайн</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="1">
              <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/company">
              Компания
            </a>
              <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="1" style="display: none;">
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/history" class="b-footer-menu__link">Кто мы</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/catalog/elektronika-optom" class="b-footer-menu__link">Корпоративным клиентам</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/owner_of_real" class="b-footer-menu__link">Арендодателям</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/charity" class="b-footer-menu__link">Благотворительность</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://job.svyaznoy.ru/" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Работа в «Связном»</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/contacts" class="b-footer-menu__link">Контакты</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/anticorruption" class="b-footer-menu__link">Политика по&nbsp;противодействию<br>коррупции</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="2">
              <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/help">
              Помощь покупателю
            </a>
              <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="2" style="display: none;">
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/feedback/add-review" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обратная связь</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/shops" class="b-footer-menu__link">Адреса магазинов</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/obmen_vozvrat_remont" class="b-footer-menu__link">Обмен, возврат и ремонт</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/guarantee" class="b-footer-menu__link">Гарантия</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/repair-status" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Статус ремонта</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/support/contacts/addresses" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Адреса сервисных центров</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/service" class="b-footer-menu__link">Дополнительные услуги и сервис</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-menu__col" data-footer-col="">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__header" data-accordion-btn="3">
              <a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/press_center">
              Пресс-центр
            </a>
              <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="b-footer-menu__list" data-accordion-target="3" style="display: none;">
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/history" class="b-footer-menu__link">История</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/mission" class="b-footer-menu__link">Миссия и ценности</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/news/press" class="b-footer-menu__link">Пресс-релизы</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/media_about_us" class="b-footer-menu__link">СМИ о нас</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UhyjwJ6wZbUX-UxlFVTELnYi8bnxuhmg" target="_blank" class="b-footer-menu__link">Фотографии</a></li>
              <li class="b-footer-menu__line"><a href="https://www.svyaznoy.ru/store/contacts_for_media" class="b-footer-menu__link">Контакты для прессы</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-menu__column">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__col is-mobile-not">
            <div class="b-footer-menu__contacts">
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
                <a href="tel:84952870000">8 (495) 287-00-00</a>
              </div>
              Интернет-магазин
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
                <a href="tel:88007005000">8 (800) 700-50-00</a>
              </div>
              Связной Поддержка
              <div class="b-footer-menu__header _xl">
                <a href="tel:88007009922">8 (800) 700-99-22</a>
              </div>
              Корпоративным клиентам
            </div>
            <div class="b-footer-menu__socials">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/svyaznoy.ru" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-fb"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://vk.com/svyaznoy" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-vk"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/svyaznoy_ru" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
              </a>
              <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svyaznoy_russia/?hl=ru" target="_blank">
                <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="b-footer-menu__ga">
              <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop" target="_blank" class="_gp" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a><br>
              <a href="https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki/id1062774471" target="_blank" class="_as" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/apps.apple.com\/ru\/app\/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki\/id1062774471&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
              <br>
              <a href="https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139" target="_blank" class="_ag" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/appgallery.cloud.huawei.com\/marketshare\/app\/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-border">
        <div class="b-footer-border__inner"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-rel" data-footer-col="">
        <div class="b-footer-menu__header is-mobile-only" data-accordion-btn="4">
          Другие проекты
          <i class="icon-angle-down-white b-footer-menu__header-icon is-mobile-only"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-rel__list" data-accordion-target="4" style="display: none;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-bottom">
        <div class="b-footer-copy-wrapper">
          <div class="b-footer-copy">© ООО «Сеть Связной» 2002—2021. Все права защищены. Указанная в интернет-магазине цена товаров и условия их приобретения действительны на текущую дату.</div>
        </div>
        <a class="b-footer-stop-covid _big lazy lazy-loaded" href="https://ecomvscovid.ru/" target="_blank" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/web/svyaznoy/img/footer/covidlogo.svg&quot;);">
        Зона безопасного сервиса. Стоп COVID.
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile">
        <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__row">
          <div class="b-footer-menu__socials">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/svyaznoy.ru" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-fb"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://vk.com/svyaznoy" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-vk"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/svyaznoy_ru" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/svyaznoy_russia/?hl=ru" target="_blank">
              <i class="icon-instagram"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__right-col">
            <a class="b-footer-stop-covid _small lazy" data-original="https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/web/svyaznoy/img/footer/covidlogo.svg" href="https://ecomvscovid.ru/" target="_blank">
            Зона безопасного сервиса. Стоп COVID.
          </a>
            <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel">
              <a class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel-link" href="tel:8 (495) 287-00-00">8 (495) 287-00-00</a>
              <div class="b-footer-contacts-mobile__tel-descr">Интернет магазин</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="b-footer-menu__ga _mobile">
          <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop" target="_blank" class="_gp" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=ru.svyaznoy.shop&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
          <a href="https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki/id1062774471" target="_blank" class="_as" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/apps.apple.com\/ru\/app\/svaznoj-internet-magazin-elektroniki\/id1062774471&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
          <a href="https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com/marketshare/app/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139" target="_blank" class="_ag" data-app-logo-event="" data-gtm-params="{&quot;eventContextGTM&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/appgallery.cloud.huawei.com\/marketshare\/app\/C102123139?locale=ru_RU&amp;source=appshare&amp;subsource=C102123139&quot;,&quot;eventLocationGTM&quot;:&quot;\u0424\u0443\u0442\u0435\u0440&quot;}"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </footer>


  <script src="commons.bundle.js.Без названия"></script>
  <script src="subcategory.bundle.js.Без названия"></script>
  <script src="testsite3.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      let subcategoryflag = '';
      $('.submenu__item a').click(function(event) {
        /*subcategoryflag=$(this).innerHTML;*/
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajaxsubcategory.php',
          data: {
            subcategoryflag: $(this).innerHTML
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('.rightmenu').html(data.msg);
          }
        })
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
<?php
class ajaxValidate {

function formValidate() {
    //Put form elements into post variables (this is where you would sanitize your data)
    $subcategoryflag = $_POST['subcategoryflag'];

    //Establish values that will be returned via ajax
    $return = array();
    $return['msg'] = '';
    $return['error'] = false;

    //Begin form validation functionality
    if (!isset($subcategoryflag) || empty($subcategoryflag)){
        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] .= '<li>Error: Field1 is empty.</li>';
    }

    //Begin form success functionality
    if ($return['error'] === false){
        $return['msg'] = '<li>Test content</li>';
    }

    //Return json encoded results
    return json_encode($return);
}

}

$ajaxValidate = new ajaxValidate;
echo $ajaxValidate->formValidate();
?>
```

но переменная `$return['msg']` (`.rightmenu`) не отображается при щелчке на пункте меню, а выдается ошибка. Файл `jquery-3.6.0.min.js` взят с [Jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: похоже у тебя в адресной строке тупо адрес к файлу, и браузер не подставляет заголовок origin, нужный для аякс запроса. создай виртуальный домен на локалке и работай на нем.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Как создать виртуальный домен на локалке?

Comment: либо open server поставь https://ospanel.io/, либо все вручную - apache+php+mysql, там в инструкции по установке будет про создание домена на локалке